# Why do we need out implicit object in JSP When we are supposed to use expressions?

Tags: java, jsp

I am studying JSP. I have a doubt. When we use the Expressions in JSP, then why do we need `out` implicit object in JSP?

Can anybody explain on this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implicit objects in the JSP context (such as `session`, `request` and `response`) are available in case you need to perform logic in your JSP using these variables.  You could see if the user has a particular session variable, or get a parameter from their request or the server's response.

However, it's usually not necessary -- and if you're performing that type of logic in the JSP, it's a sign that your View is doing something that the Controller should have done.

Answer (score 1):

It's just there for convenience and backwards compatiblity. It has been there since the birth of JSP. Nowadays (although, since roughly a decade, when EL was born), you aren't supposed to use it in real world, but *scriptlets* may be still useful to do quick prototyping/demo/testing.

On the other hand, if it was removed, the compiled JSP servlet would internally not be able to write evaluated EL expressions to the response anymore ;) It is namely been declared (with a variablename as per the JSP spec) inside the compiled JSP servlet class. That's also less or more why it's accessible in the *scriptlet* scope (which is basically scoped as a method of the compiled JSP servlet class).